# Read a file with phpexcel and convert it into mysql, get arrays of multiple-choice answer

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel file with multiple choice questions.

From my current script, I can get the question and I can insert it into mysql.

How I can get the answer list?

a1 is question number 1

a2,a3,a4,a5 are choise for question number one

a6 is question number 2

a7,a8,a9,a10 are choise for question number  two

and ...

[image]

```
 foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {

                $ss= ($row * 5 + 1);
                // question row.
                $q= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $ss);
                //$q= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $q->getValue();
                $dataArr['question'][$row][$col] = $val;


            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($dataArr);
    echo "</pre>";
```

current scriot output is

```
   Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => question no 1:
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => question no 2:
                    )
)
```

and how to print answer list

```
Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => anser a,
                            [1] => anser b,
                            [2] => anser c,
                            [3] => anser d                        
)

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                             [0] => anser a,
                            [1] => anser b,
                            [2] => anser c,
                            [3] => anser d   
                        )
    )
```

ans more, thanks alot,
and sorry for my bad english
and for more information, I have done some code like so:

```
if ($row != $ss) {
                $q= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $q->getValue();
                $dataArr['question'][$row][$col] = $val;
}
```

Nothing happens.

Please if there any improvement for my script.

Thanks a lot

ok slove with bad code standard

```
 require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("abc.xlsx");

    $dataArr = array();

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
        $ss= 1;
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {

                $ss[] = ($row * 5);
                $q= $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $q->getValue();
                $dataArr[] = $val;



            }
        }
    }
unset($dataArr[0]);
for ($a = 0; $a <= 274; $a++) {
    unset($dataArr[$ss[$a]]);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_chunk($dataArr, 4));
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You need use more columns for the answers... Like this : http://i64.tinypic.com/5e772c.jpg

Comment: i dont creatr the excel. i just create the importer,

Comment: yes, if u want import it clearly, u need use more columns on your excel file.

Comment: There is thousend of question. You wanna help me edit excell file?

Comment: Your best choice is to run your script with phpstorm's debugger and evaluate the code line by line to understand what's going on.

Comment: there is no error in my script, im asking question, how get multipl choise answer list (a,b,c,d) choise, so i can import it in mysql

Comment: Are there always 4 answers to every question? Or do questions and answers have specific formats to help identify them?

Comment: Yes always 4 choice. A, b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

For more information ;

https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/

https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/wikis/Documentation.wiki

Examples are given by creator..

Comment: So Excel Reader's wiki's url is :  https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader/wikis/Documentation.wiki

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be easier making the first row of your excel file the questions and then put the answers below on the next row or rows.

The code you have is almost there. You need to read the first row, put the cell values (your questions) in a column array and then put the rest of the rows (2+) in a separate data array. Then go through your arrays, matching the columns in your column array with the values in your data array.

Then combine into a query to your database. If you want an example of this, look at this link. http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/05/07/4606.aspx

That is how they do it in there example and I did for mine and it works great.